# Is there any way to re-organise the global application menu?

Tags: unity, appmenu

In any application in Unity, the main menu for the application that has focus gives the options of 'file', 'edit', 'view', 'go', bookmarks', 'help', etc. - just like windows does. While this makes sense for anyone who's used a computer for years, it is not very intuitive - especially the first two (file and edit).

I'd like to know if the options in this menu can be re-organised.

For example, 'File' should perhaps be renamed to 'Application', because the sub-menu items like 'New folder' (in Nautilus) and 'Quit' affect the entire application. 'Preferences' and 'About' should be in that menu too by this logic. The 'Edit' menu could be renamed 'File', and have all options that affect whatever item is selected (or whichever tab or document view is opened) in the application, such as 'Copy', 'Paste', and 'Print'. The 'Properties' item should be in that menu as well.

Comment: Interesting question! I'm not sure that I agree with the need to rename them, but finding out how/if you can might be something :)

Comment: Yes, I realise the renaming - and specifically what is considered 'intuitive' -  is dependent on how each person uses and navigates the software; These were merely my suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The application menu just displays an application's menu, it doesn't generate the menu itself.

There's no real way to do what you want other than modifying the menus in each application.